# laravel s3 get image from API displaying unknown SRC when trying to mask URL

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I have a headless CMS that is serving up the image location for an S3 **private** bucket. I can access the image URL like this currently using a custom function that takes each image passed to the view and grabbing it via S3 using the Laravel S3 library.

```
return Storage::cloud()->url($newLink[1]); // This currently works
```

However what i want to now do is hide the full URL of the returned image from the view template. From my understanding i should be using the get function. Then re-writing a new URL.

```
return Storage::cloud()->get($newLink[1]);
```

However in my view now the image html displays as unknown. After some research i have found out that the Laravel module for filestorage does not process raw data for images. In addition i have some complexity as i do not want my bucket objects public.

```
<img src=(unknown) alt=''/>
```

**update**

I have fixed the above issue, by encoding the raw data from the Storage get request inside my controller and decoding it by passing the return string and the decode instructions to the img tag.

```
$base64 = base64_encode(Storage::cloud()->get($newLink[1]));
return "data:image/png;base64,".$base64;
```

After some research i have found out that the Laravel module for filestorage does not process raw data for images by default. What i want to achieve is the image with an SEO friendly URL link. I think i need to use something like https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-bucket-policies-and-apply-defense-in-depth-to-help-secure-your-amazon-s3-data/. Any help or a point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

```
//expected final outcome     
<img src='/image/my-image.jpg' alt=''/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, there were two options i could have gone with. Ultimately i wanted to secure the bucket access across headless architecture, whilst maintaining SEO friendly context and social media link friendly assets.

1st write a function to download the images locally to the web server that was calling the S3-bucket. This had the advantage of replicating the assets for added safety(as long as the file structure was kept the same), should someone on the CMS side accidentally delete the images and were unavailable to re-upload. However the downside would be replicated data and cost, that probably should be managed by S3 replication.

2nd which was the option i went for, is to setup a cloudfront distribution with my S3-bucket with a custom sub-domain and SSL. After reading this article on SEO for assets on the same domain [HERE](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-images-domain-name-seo-27213.html) with the sub-domain pointing to my bucket, i didn't need to use Laravels storage package to get images, as they could be referenced directly.

For 3 Bucket i applied an anonymous get policy to allow anyone to link images for the link friendly assets.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "AnonymousGetImages",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow-Public-Access-To-Bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*mybucket*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If anyone has a different way of approaching this, i would aprecaite the input.